# How to distinguish using google api between google suite admin and google suite business admin

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

Regular GSuite admin cannot create new team drive (only business admin can) I need to distinguish between regular GSuite admin and business GSuite admin via API.

I'm using G Suite admin SDK in java to retrieve google user, however there is no flag or variable that can help me to differ between the two.
Is there a way to do it?

```
(AbstractGoogleClient.Builder) client;

client.login(Directory.Builder.class);

Directory.Users.Get request = ((Directory) client.users().get(EmailOfAdmin-RegularOrBusiness);

User user = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: really interesting...

Answer (score 0):

Regular G Suite Admin API uses to retrieve a user:

> `GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/userKey`

wherein, `userKey` can be the user's primary email address, the unique user id, or one of the user's alias email addresses.

While with G Suite Business, files belong to a team instead of an individual. Each user in your organization can store unlimited Gmail messages, Gmail Photos and files in Drive.

> The [Drive activity report](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive) returns information about how your account's
>   users manage, modify, and share their Google Drive documents.

See [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list) for the information about request's query strings and response properties. For information about specific events related to to Google Drive, see [Drive event names](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive).

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [RoleAssignments.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/privileges/list) endpoint. This should give you information about the roles associated with a certain user and what kind of admin they are.

Check out this page for more information on Roles: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-roles